# SQL: UN-PIVOT and separate by individual score

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I am using SQL Server 2008 and am trying to write a query that splits columns into individual rows. I am pulling count data and need to transform it into individual scores.

**Example:**
5 students answer ‘always’ and an answer of ‘always’ = 3 points;
4 students answer ‘usually’ and answer of ‘usually’ = 2 points

Instead of having a field named ‘always’ with a count of 5 and a field named ‘usually’ with a count of 4, I would like to have one field named ‘Score’ with 5 rows of 3 and 4 rows of 2.

I have started my query by using an UNPIVOT, however, it does not split the data as described. I have included sample data and my desired results below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Always = 3 points  
Usually = 2 points      
Sometimes = 1 points    
Never = 0 points
```

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST(QUESTION VARCHAR(15), STUDENT VARCHAR(15), STARTDATE DATE, ALWAYS INT, USUALLY INT, SOMETIMES INT, NEVER INT)

INSERT #TEST(QUESTION, STUDENT, STARTDATE, ALWAYS, USUALLY, SOMETIMES, NEVER)
VALUES
('A','BOB','01/01/2016',2,1,1,2),
('A','BOB','03/01/2016',3,1,1,0),
('A','JIM','01/01/2016',2,1,2,0),
('A','JIM','03/01/2016',4,1,0,0),
('BB','BOB','03/01/2016',2,1,1,2),
('BB','BOB','07/01/2016',3,1,1,0),
('BB','JIM','03/01/2016',2,1,2,0),
('BB','JIM','07/01/2016',4,1,0,0)
```

**Query:**

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #TEST
    --WHERE 
    --  QUESTION = 'A' 
    --AND STUDENT IN ('BOB','JIM')
    --AND STARTDATE = '2016-01-01'
)   
SELECT QUESTION, STUDENT, STARTDATE, SCORE
FROM 
    (   SELECT QUESTION, STUDENT, STARTDATE, ALWAYS, USUALLY, SOMETIMES, NEVER
        FROM A
    ) P
UNPIVOT
    ( SCORE FOR Z IN (ALWAYS, USUALLY, SOMETIMES, NEVER)
    ) AS unpvt
```

**Expected Results: for 1st 2 rows**

```
QUESTION|STUDENT|STARTDATE|SCORE|
--------+-------+---------+-----+
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |3    |--ALWAYS
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |3    |--ALWAYS
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |2    |--USUALLY
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |1    |--SOMETIMES
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |0    |--NEVER
A       |BOB    |1/1/2016 |0    |--NEVER
A       |BOB    |3/1/2016 |3    |--ALWAYS
A       |BOB    |3/1/2016 |3    |--ALWAYS
A       |BOB    |3/1/2016 |3    |--ALWAYS
A       |BOB    |3/1/2016 |2    |--USUALLY
A       |BOB    |3/1/2016 |1    |--SOMETIMES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY and an ad-hoc tally table

```
Select A.Question
      ,A.Student
      ,A.StartDate
      ,B.Score
 From  #Test A
 Cross Apply ( values (Always,3)
                     ,(Usually,2)
                     ,(Sometimes,1)
                     ,(Never,0) 
              ) B(Cnt,Score)
 Join (Select Top 100 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) C
   on (C.N <= B.Cnt)
 Where Student='Bob' and question ='A'
```

Returns

```
Question    Student StartDate   Score
A           BOB     2016-01-01  3
A           BOB     2016-01-01  3
A           BOB     2016-01-01  2
A           BOB     2016-01-01  1
A           BOB     2016-01-01  0
A           BOB     2016-01-01  0
A           BOB     2016-03-01  3
A           BOB     2016-03-01  3
A           BOB     2016-03-01  3
A           BOB     2016-03-01  2
A           BOB     2016-03-01  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your suggestion works for my sample data set. Can you explain this "JOIN (SELECT TOP 100 N=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) FROM master..spt_values )"? I have never seen this table used and am not understanding why you used it or selected the top 100.

Comment: @JBritton Just creating an ad-hoc tally/numbers table of 100 records.  This will allow the "expansion" of your record set.

Comment: @JBritton The Top 100 was an arbitrary value.  If you will never see more than say 10 responses, then make it Top 10.   It does no harm having a larger value.   The sub-query is resolved once

Answer (score 0):

If you have a manageable number of columns to unpivot, I usually just make separate queries for each, and combined with a `UNION ALL`.

Here is the general idea:

```
SELECT Question, Student, StartDate, Always AS Score
FROM #TEST
WHERE ...

UNION ALL

SELECT Question, Student, StartDate, Usually AS Score
FROM #TEST
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

using `cross apply (values...)` to unpivot your data, a numbers table for 1-9, and a points table, we can do something like this:

```
with a as (
  select *
  from #test
  where question = 'A' 
    and student = 'bob'
    --and student in ('bob','jim')
    --and startdate = '20160101'
)
, points as (
  select Answer, Points
  from (values ('Always',3),('Usually',2),('Sometimes',1),('Never',0)
    ) p (Answer,Points)
)
, numbers as (
  select n 
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
    ) t(n)
)
, unp as (
  select 
      a.question
    , a.student
    , StartDate=convert(varchar(10),a.startdate,120)
    , x.AnswerCount
    , x.Answer
  from a
    cross apply (
      values ([Always],'Always')
        , ([Usually],'Usually')
        , ([Sometimes],'Sometimes')
        , ([Never],'Never')
      ) x (AnswerCount,Answer)
)
select 
    unp.question
  , unp.student
  , unp.startdate
  , score = p.points
  , unp.answer
  from unp
    inner join numbers n on n.n<=unp.AnswerCount
    inner join points p on unp.answer=p.answer
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GQCN45867

returns:

```
+----------+---------+------------+-------+-----------+
| question | student | startdate  | score |  answer   |
+----------+---------+------------+-------+-----------+
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     3 | Always    |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     3 | Always    |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     2 | Usually   |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     1 | Sometimes |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     0 | Never     |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-01 |     0 | Never     |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-03 |     3 | Always    |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-03 |     3 | Always    |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-03 |     3 | Always    |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-03 |     2 | Usually   |
| A        | bob     | 2016-01-03 |     1 | Sometimes |
+----------+---------+------------+-------+-----------+
```